# JavaFX multithreading and controller class

Tags: java, multithreading, controller, javafx-8

i am trying to execute multiple countdown timers simultaneously using javafx . currently used multithreading. now i am trying to print the timers in labels so as to display on screen , however unable to do so because i cant access the controller class to print it. how do i achieve printing the timer value on labels using my thread class. my timer value should be printed in labels in a gridpane , so i get the constraints from the controller class and then print accordingly.

```
package tabapplication;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import tabapplication.TabApplication;
import tabapplication.FXMLDocumentController;
class Rdt implements Runnable {
   private Thread t;
   private String threadName;

   Rdt( String name){
       threadName = name;
       System.out.println("Creating " +  threadName );
   }
   public void run() {
      System.out.println("Running " +  threadName );
      try {
          final Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            int s = 60;
            int m=30;
            public void run() {
                s--;
                if(s<0 &&  m>0)
                {m--;
                s=59;
                }
                if(s<10)
                {  System.out.println(Integer.toString(m)+":"+0+Integer.toString(s)); }
                else
                {System.out.println(Integer.toString(m)+":"+Integer.toString(s));}


                if(m==0 && s==0)
                    timer.cancel();
            }
        }, 0, 10);
            Thread.sleep(50);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " interrupted.");
     }
     System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
   }

   public void start ()
   {
      System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
      if (t == null)
      {
         t = new Thread (this, threadName);
         t.start ();
      }
   }
   public static void main(String args[]) {

      Rdt R1 = new Rdt( "Thread-1");
      Thread obj1=new Thread(R1);
      obj1.start();

      Rdt R2 = new Rdt( "Thread-2");
     Thread obj2=new Thread(R2);
     obj2.start();
   }   
}
```

Comment: "I can't access the controller class...".  Why not? Presumably in your JavaFX application you would actually instantiate these timers *from* the controller (e.g. as a response to a user action).

Comment: I want the timers to run independently and simultaneously , but in my case only one time is runs and other stops. That is why I am using thread for different timers. From fxml controller I am calling above mentioned Java code. but I have to place each timer at a specific position in a grid. Not able to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Give your `Rdt` class a callback to execute when the time it represents changes. This could be in the form of a `Consumer<String>`, for example:

```
class Rdt implements Runnable {
   private Thread t;
   private String threadName;

   private Consumer<String> callback ;

   Rdt( String name, Consumer<String> callback){
       threadName = name;
       System.out.println("Creating " +  threadName );
       this.callback = callback ;
   }
   public void run() {
      System.out.println("Running " +  threadName );
      try {
          final Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            int s = 60;
            int m=30;
            public void run() {
                s--;
                if(s<0 &&  m>0)
                {m--;
                s=59;
                }
                if(s<10)
                {  callback.accept(Integer.toString(m)+":"+0+Integer.toString(s)); }
                else
                {callback.accept(Integer.toString(m)+":"+Integer.toString(s));}


                if(m==0 && s==0)
                    timer.cancel();
            }
        }, 0, 10);
            Thread.sleep(50);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " interrupted.");
     }
     System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
   }

   // ...
}
```

Now from your controller class you can just start the timer with:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Label timerLabel ;

    @FXML
    private void startTimer() {
        Rdt timer = new Rdt("Timer-1", timerLabel::setText);
        timer.run();
    }
}
```

A couple of asides:

1. There is no need to create threads here. The [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class *already* creates a background thread for you, so this will run in a background thread without explicitly creating one.
2. You're really reinventing the wheel in a lot of places. The standard libraries already have, for example, a [`Duration` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which can be used to represent minutes and seconds, and which already implements all the arithmetic for you. Consider:

   ```
   public class Rdt {

       private String name ;

       private Consumer<Duration> callback ;

       private Duration time ;

       public Rdt(String name, Consumer<Duration> callback) {
           this.name = name ;
           this.callback = callback ;
       }

       public void startTimer() {
           Timer timer = new Timer();
           time = Duration.ofMinutes(30);
           timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   time = time.minusSeconds(1);
                   callback.accept(time);
                   if (time.isZero()) {
                       timer.cancel();
                   }
               }
           }, 0, 10);
       }
   }
   ```

and similarly, the `DateTimeFormatter` class knows how to format times nicely as strings, so from the controller you would do:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("mm:ss");
Rdt timer = new Rdt("Timer-1", time -> timerLabel.setText(formatter.format(time)));
timer.start();
```

Comment: if the label where i want to print the time is inside a grid pane , what do i do to print it there. Currently the gridpane was made using the scene builder so it is present in the fxml file. I was printing time through my controller class. approach was to call Rdt class for different instances of timer and return values to controller class to print it in the label , which i am unable to achieve.  could you suggest edits or alternative measures to perform the same. @James_D

Comment: private Consumer<Duration> callback ; generationg error cannot find symbol in class in class Rdt

Comment: Fr. the first comment, the answer shows explicitly how to do that. Not sure what you are missing. For the second, did you include the imports?

Comment: following packages imported
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*
import tabapplication.Table;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.*;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.event.Event;import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.*;

Comment: You didn't add the imports for `Consumer` (`java.util.function.Consumer`) and `Duration` (`java.time.Duration`).